# Django, полно ошибок в консоли

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Изучаю Django, пишу небольшой проект в процесе обучения.
Постоянно в терминале PyCharm куча ошибок, такого типа:

```
[26/Dec/2018 04:27:03] "GET /static/styles/fonts/RobotoMedium.ttf HTTP/1.1" 404 1711
[26/Dec/2018 04:27:03] "GET /about HTTP/1.1" 200 981
[26/Dec/2018 04:27:48] "GET /static/styles/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 941
```

В браузере все работает исправно, стили грузит, все как и должно.
Как исправить ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не ошибки, а сообщения о запросах. Исправлять ничего не нужно.

Comment: Оно должно быть красным текстом ?

Comment: Это PyCharm так раскрашивает. В системной консоли они серые.